# Sound volume indicator in top panel is resetting top panel upon mouse click or hover

Tags: 11.10, sound, indicator

I've installed the system monitor indicator applet and weather indicator applet. all else is the same. Do you think compiz is the problem? Can I reinstall the volume indicator applet?

Answer (score 0):

keep an eye on this filed bug

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-sound/+bug/883592

right now is flagged as invalid but people keeps asking so I still keep my hopes is really annoying, don't know how to debug it and been looking for a solution for weeks.. good luck